# How to prevent toolbar and navigation bar blinking during shared view activity transition?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- enable window content transitions -->
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>

</style>
```

or 
excluding from java class navigation and statusbar from transition

```
    View decor = ((PhotosActivity)context).getWindow().getDecorView();
    View statusBar = decor.findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);
    View navBar = decor.findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground);


    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
            makeSceneTransitionAnimation((PhotosActivity) context,
                    new  android.support.v4.util.Pair<>(photo, "photo")
                    new android.support.v4.util.Pair<>(statusBar, Window.STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND_TRANSITION_NAME),
                    new android.support.v4.util.Pair<>(navBar, Window.NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND_TRANSITION_NAME));
            );
    context.startActivity(photoIntent, options.toBundle());
```

it continues blinking

Comment: Hi @A.A.I.A, did you ever got to fix this?

Comment: @ Nemesis no, I see only google apps like play store animations work as expected.but no real working sample

Answer (score 4):

`View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();` this `decor` view used to get the default action bar.

`makeSceneTransitionAnimation` used to define the shared widgets between the two activities.

To prevent flickering for action bar, status bar and navigation bar. Please add these lines of code in the `onCreate` method for the 2 Activities:

```
Fade fade = new Fade();
View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
fade.excludeTarget(decor.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_container), true);
fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);
```